# Data Menor e Maior que X dias MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho um campo na tabela chamado `registro_data_instalacao` do tipo *date*, preciso exibir os registros com o `registro_data_instalacao` em que a data seja maior que 3 dias e menor que 30 dias, tentei da forma abaixo, mas, sem sucesso.

```
SELECT *
FROM registro
WHERE registro_data_instalacao >= (CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 3 DAY)
  AND registro_data_instalacao <= (CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: Veja se essa resposta lhe resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793634/5074998

Comment: Se os links acima e a resposta dada não resolverem, queira [edit] a postagem com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o [**DATE_SUB**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp), como abaixo;

```
SELECT *
FROM registro
WHERE v.date > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
  AND v.date < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```